# What does the Comedy Specs extra do?

Tags: lego-harry-potter-years-5-7

The first extra that you can unlock is called **Comedy Specs**.  However, turning on this extra does not appear to make any changes to the game.  What does this extra actually do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get the Spectre Specs (sp?) they will be the slinky eyeball glasses instead. Same function though (a silly prop replacement like Carrot Wands).